# Solving for the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the rules of solving for the determinants of a matrix and I totally thought I was doing this right, but the answer output is incorrect.

I took the approach that I was adding the $a, b$ and $c$, so nothing would change. However, I notice I am multiplying the second row by scalars, so I just figured it would be $-4^3 \cdot (1)$ for $-64$. Can someone explain the intuition behind the solution please. Thanks for the help.

Never mind, I realized my mistake was I was taking the value of $-4^3$, however, the entire row was just being multiplied by the value of $-4$. Therefore, the final answer came out to be $-4$.

> Given $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
> a&b&c\\
> d&e&f\\
> g&h&i
> \end{bmatrix}=1$$
>   Find the determinat
>   $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
> a&b&c\\
> -4d+a&-4e+b&-4f+c\\
> g&h&i
> \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

If ${\rm det}\ A=1$, can you calculate 
  $$  {\rm det}\ (\left(  \begin{matrix} 1&0&0\\ 1 &-4 &0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{matrix} \right) A) $$

Answer (score 1):

We can inspect the row operations to convert the matrix with known determinant into the matrix with unknown determinant.  Row operations change the determinant in certain ways (see e.g. [this article](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant)).

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & u \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\det=1}
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets -4R_2}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
-4d & -4e & -4f \\
g & h & u \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\det=???}
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2+R_1}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
-4d+a & -4e+b & -4f+c \\
g & h & u \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\det=???}.
$$